origami SNY t28
It's been a long time since I've posted an origami puzzle!
Fold the shape into a rectangle such that the rectangle is 28 layers thick everywhere. The purple part is the puzzle.

Although solutions are not required to be applicable in real life, using an actual sheet of paper is a great visualization tool.
A puzzle for this type of orgami puzzle game made by Ωmega_3301, similar to this question.

Will try this tomorrow, need to get stiffer paper and a working printer first!

Just to remind you, solutions are not required to be applicable in real life.

@PDT good luck trying to fold a piece of paper to 28 layers! :P

@BeastlyGerbil haha! My aim is to have just a visual aid, these puzzles become much easier with some paper in hand! I suck at visualizing intricate shapes hence why I could never paint very well!

Here it is.

 Fold it vertically along the red lines.
 You get the 13x2 stripe shown at the bottom.
 The color shows on which row each square ends up.

 Then fold it horizontally to the 1x2 rectangle shown at the right.



You can also fold it to a square:

 

 The colors show where each triangle ends up.  There are 28 of each color.




noooooo i wanted to tackle the puzzle today but you stole it :(
will be posting solution if i find a different one though

Well... on this site you cannot wait a week and expect the problem to remain unsolved for you.

yeah good point, ig congratulations to you for solving this puzzle! (i actually intended for some puzzles of this type to be included in my puzzle book but decided no for some reasons)
